# Error when using AASTeX in LyX

Tags: errors, lyx

I am getting an error whenever I am trying to view the document in Preview. The two errors are

> "LaTeX Error: Command \singlespace already defined."

and

> "LaTeX Error: Command \doublespace already defined."

I am a n00b when it comes to LaTeX, which is why I am using LyX.

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Have you added anything to the LaTeX preamble, or done any other modifications? (Those errors wouldn't occur with the default template, so you must have done something.) Ideally, strip your `.lyx` file down to the minimum showing the problem, and edit your question to include either the exported LaTeX source, or the contents of the `.lyx` file (it is a plain text file, you can open it in Notepad or similar, and copy everything).